# How to boot Windows7 from USB (WinToUSB)

Tags: windows-7, usb

I dropped my computer and trashed the HDD - when I try to start Windows I hear a clicking sound on startup and it freezes.

Unfortunately, I need to recover data from the HDD. I used WinToUSB to burn a Windows 7 ISO on the USB and run the OS from there and I hoped I could access at least some of the files I need on the HDD.

When I try to boot Win from the USB I can't do it even though I have disabled all other boot options but the USB or I choose boot from USB in the boot menu specifically - the computer still boots the HDD. I tried to remove the HDD, put the USB in and run Win and it works but I don't have access to my HDD.

Hope someone can help me out.

Best!

Comment: I'll be completely honest, I think your best bet would to utilize a Linux Live CD and get the data out of your HDD that way. Although, if what you're saying about your HDD is true (trashed the HDD) then you're SOL.

Comment: I have never used anything but Windows. I read a bit about Linux Live CD and there seem to be options. What should I use?

Comment: If you can boot removing the HDD you can use put it in an external HDD case (they are cheap) and plug it as an USB device (supposing the disk still works fine).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinPE (Windows Personal Edition), which is designed to run from USB or CD. The easiest way to build it is install an application that builds a "rescue disk", such as an [antivirus](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/13-antivirus-rescue-cds-software-compared-in-search-for-the-best-rescue-disk/) or imaging tool (e.g. [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)). Most of these WinPE versions include Windows Explorer or an equivalent, or *if* you can run an application from the CMD prompt, use [Q-Dir *Portable*](https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=Q-Dir) or equivalent file browser. Of course, copying files from the bad HDD may not be possible if it is damaged.

If you have more experience and want to try some tools that *might* be able to salvage some data, other than by copying files (assuming that the damaged disk can be mounted), [download an ISO for a rescue disk with a more complete set of tools](https://techtalk.gfi.com/top-5-free-rescue-discs-for-your-sys-admin-toolkit/).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to continue using your computer (only HDD crashed, computer OK) you may get a new HDD into your computer, install your old Windows (or a new version) and connect your crashed HDD to your computer.

Then you can copy the data you need to recover (hope it can be recovered) to your new and reliable HDD.

I know that this alternate solution is not what you have asked, but if it sounds like a solution for your data recovery problem you will not need to spend time researching about how to boot from USB etc.